# RACI Matrix - Accountability

Tags: resource-planning, project-management-style, human-resources, responsibility

Can a task under [RACI matrix](https://www.projectsmart.co.uk/raci-matrix.php) be accountable by 2 resources?

E.g.: Both the Project Manager and the Development Team Head are accountable for the project quality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it can't. In the RACI format, the Accountable person is the one ultimately answerable for the correct completion of the task.
It is also the one who delegates the work to those marked as "Responsible".

As such, there has to be only one accountable specified.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsibility_assignment_matrix

Comment: True. Even the link I've shared in my question says so, but I was just wondering whether it's a rule to be followed that there can be only one person to be accountable or it's a just a concept that can be adjusted based on the situation / scenario to have 2 or more accountable resources.

Comment: Hi @SahanDeSilva, my take in this situation is that it's better to stick with the rule until you master the practice well enough to know when and why to break it. More specifically, setting 2 people as equally accountable may generate confusion as to whom exactly has to take up something or delegate what to whom. I personally prefer the concept of trust + shared accountability pushed by more agile frameworks and methodologies, but I understand the reason why the rule exists.